# UitableViewcell Height Issue how can solve

Tags: uitableview, height, cell

[when i scrol the cell one two time at that show to perfact but when scrol to more then times so that showing the issues.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B16Ut.png)

float heightofCell=0.0;
    heightofCell=FirstView.frame.size.height + MidView.frame.size.height + BottomView.frame.size.height + 10;
return heightofCell;